# Gaoxing (高兴) vs. Kaixin (开心)

Tags: word-choice

A few of the translation apps I use show both to mean happy.  Are these synonyms or is there a deeper level for one, like joy might be considered deeper than happy?

Comment: They are interchangeable in most cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 高 = highly; 兴= delighted
>
> **高兴** = happy; **glad**; delighted
>
> *describe a  emotional state of being delighted*

~

> 开= open; 心 = heart
>
> **开心** = happy; **joyful**
>
> *metaphorically describe an effect of being happy*

Both 高兴  and 开心 means 'happy', but with different emphasis.

For example, if you are glad that you didn't get killed in a car accident, you can say: "我很高興我還活著" (I am glad that I am still alive), but you wouldn't say: "我很開心我還活著" (I am joyful that I am still alive)

Another example,  We use 我很高興見到你 (I am glad to see you) as a polite greeting, but "見到你我很開心" (seeing you make me happy) would be a more passionate expression.

- 开心 is also more personal, e.g. "今天是我最开心的一天" is more natural than "今天是我最高興的一天"

> Another word for 'happy:
>
> 快 = satisfactory; 樂 = delight
>
> **快樂** = **happy**/ joyful/ cheerful (describe a joyful emotional state). It can be a noun or an adjective

Answer (score 1):

- 高兴[gāo xìng]

  - (愉快而兴奋) glad; happy; pleased; elated; joyful; cheerful:
  - I'm very glad to see you. 我见到你很高兴。
  - He is sure to be pleased [happy] at the news. 他听到这个消息一定很高兴。
- 开心[kāi xīn]

  - （快乐; 舒畅） feel happy; rejoice; joyful; be delighted; have a grand time:
  - His joy was immense. 他开心极了。
  - The children dance round him in delight. 孩子们开心地围着他跳舞。

Answer (score 1):

不管说哪一个都能 了解你的意思
no much difference, whichever you use could make people know you are happy

Answer (score 0):

Just like the difference between Happy and Delighted/Pleased.

In a word, when comes to daily usage, no difference, unless bringing up to an academic/professional level.